# Is there a way to query maven central for a package and return the license?

Tags: maven

I'm not a developer per se; I'm charged with reviewing and approving open source.  It would be useful to have a command line utility that reaches into [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central) with package name and return the license.  Something named "query-license" might be used like this "query-license openjpa", and, return "apache 2.0".

I'm barely familiar with rest api's, and, use insomnia occasionally to, for example, pull down github issue information from our repo's.  I tried using "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.openjpa/openjpa/3.1.2" as my GET, and it returns their web page; I just want the license.  I'm willing to make a curl call if maven central supports that.  I can't find any useful doc on an api if one exists.

I'm also barely familiar with maven, and, tried using maven license plugin.  I'm still working on that, I think I have some settings.xml changes to make.  It could easily be I'm just hosing up the maven command syntax, too.

Comment: `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:license-maven-plugin:2.0.0:aggregate-download-licenses \
  -Dlicense.excludedScopes=system,test \
  -Dlicense.sortByGroupIdAndArtifactId=true` will download the licenses which are defined in your pom file and produces file of licences. https://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise.  I think this will only show first-level licenses.  It also requires me to know the appropriate pom file and have it properly configured; I am dealing with dozens of apps with hundreds if not thousands of packages.  I need to know the licenses all the way down the dependency tree, too, not just the top level defined in the pom.

Comment: It will aggregate all licenses of your current project. But yes if you have a larger area I would suggest to take a look a https://www.sonatype.com/nexus/firewall